# include mysql connection remotely php

Tags: php, mysql

I know how to connect to a MySQL DB on a remote server. What I want to do is, connect to the remote mysql server on the clients site without them being able to see my connection credentials by simply downloading the sqlconnect.php file.

the reason for this is because I have built multiple sites that are almost identical. they are essentially re-seller sites. I built it in a way that one database handles all the sites and simple "site ID's" passed on by each site determine the content delivered.
I need to connect to Mysql remotely but dont want to leave the connection file on each persons server. I'm not so much interested in protecting the rest of the code, just the mysql connection credentials itself.

Comment: Why don't you create a separate MySQL user for every site? Or is this about trying to protect your database? Because in that case you might want to re-think your strategy, since if a) your code runs on a client system and b) it has write access to your database, you must assume that the person having access to your code also has access to the database.

Comment: Its about trying to protect my database and your right! Even if they dont have DB credentials they would be able to read/write to the DB with the connected scripts. That defeats the purpose of the security measure. I do need to rethink this. perhaps I will just host all client reseller sites myself.

Comment: What you want is not possible. PHP code cannot establish an SQL connection but at the same time not know how to establish this connection. You either want: separate credentials for each user, an SQL proxy/connection bundler which anonymises the actual connection, or a non-SQL API.

Comment: "perhaps I will just host all client reseller sites myself. " - that's a solution. Putting a webservice between the MySQL server and the other servers would be, too. Or maybe multiple MySQL credentials each having only the permission to select a specific view (per account) could work as well.

Comment: Thank you all and thanks VolkerK, I found this link about the views: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283982/restricting-certain-users-to-only-their-data-in-a-common-table